# Core Data Import data in background with rollback

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Sorry about the title, i couldn't figure out how to summarize my long question.

My app has offline data in core data. At user will, it can be refreshed by downloading latest from the server. Images are also part of the download. When user cancel the update operation or something happens in the middle, i would like to leave the data in the same state when it was before the update operation began.

Many forums and blogs recommended each secondary thread to create its own context. As image downloads will be under concurrent operation queue, many threads would be in action. I don't want to save in each thread to avoid leaving database in incomplete state.

Will it be good if i create replica of my active entities for secondary thread, so that all those secondary thread can save, edit as they like. When the entire update process is over i can port the data to primary tables/entities in a single thread.

What would be the recommended approach to the given scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendations you have been reading about were generally correct. Only, it is not a secondary thread that creates a context, but actually the other way round.

You create a child context of your main managed object context, making sure that you use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` when adding your persistent store. Use the `performBlock` API which will automatically manage threading and memory for you. If the download fails, you simply throw away your child context.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds very promising to my scenario. Can you elaborate this? Or Refer some links for more details?

Comment: You could start with or read through a [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1).

Comment: Even more specific to the solution in discussion here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/